# dont quite understand string.format, and the java documentation

Tags: java

i couldnt find anything specific for this, so i was wondering how do i use string format to make a double value output in exactly this format $XXXX.XX, could anyone show me how this is done, and break each piece of the method down of what it is actually doing because i just dont know how to apply what i see on the docs im using to what im trying to output in the method and i would much rather understand what each 'command/argument' means or does so that I dont have to ask a question like this.

https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-format // the docs im using

the code im trying to format,
value taken from explicit

```
double dollarAmt = String.format(????);
```

Comment: `String.format` will return a `String` **not** `double`.

Comment: `String dollarAmt = String.format("$%.2f", Math.PI);` is `"$3.14"`

Comment: If you want to format a number, possibly consider `DecimalFormat` instead.

Answer (score 0):

> so i was wondering how do i use string format to make a double value
> output in exactly this format $XXXX.XX

There are a lot of ways to do that.  Here is one:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

...

double someNumber = 21.12;
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("$0000.00");
String result = formatter.format(someNumber);
```